# How to import static from a class

Tags: python-3.x, import

I have previously used importlib as a dynamic importing from a class by doing this:

```
def load_store(store: str) -> importlib:
    """
    Imports the correct path for given store
    :param store:
    :return:
    """
    mod = importlib.import_module(f"lib.vendors.{store}")
    class_pointer = getattr(mod, store)()
    return class_pointer
```

However the problem I have seen is that for some reason it calls the importlib 602 times!! whenever I do have this function[image: 602 times]

on a code that only calls the function once.

```
from lib.scraper import product_data
from lib.utils import load_store

# To test specific store and link
store: str = "footlockerse"
link: str = "https://www.footlocker.se/en/product/BarelyGreen-Black-White/316700362904"

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Utils
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
store_class = load_store(store=store) # <--- Calls it only once


def main():
    product_data(store_class=store_class)
    store = store, link = link, params = "product_page")


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

I have later on tested to call the import static and the issue went away, However my problem is that I do have around 46 imports that I need to implement and I wonder if I could somehow import only the needed import by given the "store" variable, for example if I have given footlockerse then we import only footlockerse, is that possible?

e.g.

```
test = "footlockerse"

from lib.vendors.test import test
```

Comment: Are you sure these imports are actually just *your* import? ``importlib`` is a Python implementation of what is used by ``import``, and it may-or-may-not use itself recursively (i.e. import submodules and dependencies via ``importlib``).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Correct, I do not use importlib anywhere besides the load_store function, thats the only place I actually do a importlib

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I'm not asking whether you use ``importlib.import_module`` more than once. I'm asking whether you have checked that ``importlib`` doesn't use ``importlib``. I assume it does, by the way – it's kind of the point.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Ah, yeah, I have not checked that and im not sure how I can test that as well. If you could tell me how I could come back with an answer :D